# Swift Struct as Request Body

Tags: json, swift, postgresql, vapor, decodable

Trying to send data into my postgreSQL database using Vapor and Swift.

Here is example code (Swift Struct as Request Body)

```
struct ToDoResponseModel: Codable {
   var id: Int
   var Name: String
   var isComplete: Bool
}

let url = URL(string: "http://localhost:8080/todos")
guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }
var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// Set HTTP Request Header
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

let newTodoItem = ToDoResponseModel(id: 300, Name: "Urgent task 2", isComplete: true)

do {
    let jsonData = try JSONEncoder().encode(newTodoItem)
    request.httpBody = jsonData
}catch let jsonErr{
    print(jsonErr)
}

let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

    if let error = error {
        print("Error took place \(error)")
        return
    }
    guard let data = data else {return}

    do {
        let todoItemModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(ToDoResponseModel.self, from: data)
        print("Response data:\n \(todoItemModel)")
        print("todoItemModel Name: \(todoItemModel.Name)")
        print("todoItemModel id: \(todoItemModel.id )")
    } catch let jsonErr {
        print(jsonErr)
    } 
}
task.resume()
```

But I faced the next error:

> *keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "id", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "No
>   value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"id\", intValue:
>   nil) (\"id\").", underlyingError: nil))*

Error fixed on this line:

```
let todoItemModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(ToDoResponseModel.self, from: data)
```

and Vapor sends me :

> *[ ERROR ] DecodingError.keyNotFound: Value required for key 'IsComplete'. (ErrorMiddleware.swift:26)*

Comment: Have you checked that `data` contains a key-pair for `isComplete`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're sending `isComplete` from the client side but the Vapor server is expecting `IsComplete` (capital I)